Access the main plot axis in backtrader
I wand to add custom plot elements e.g. a box between buy and sell trades. The axis ax is normally created like this: fig, ax = plt.subplots()
How can I access it in Backtester's plot?
            ax = ???
            width = (bt.num2date(self.sell_dt) - bt.num2date(self.buy_dt)).total_seconds() / (60*60*24)
            height = self.sell_price - self.buy_price
            rect = patches.Rectangle((self.buy_dt, self.buy_price), width, height, linewidth=1, edgecolor='yellow', facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
            ax.add_patch(rect)


Aiv, you can try this code
import backtrader as bt
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from backtrader import plot
import pandas as pd

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

df = yf.download(
    "BTC-USD",
    start="2024-01-01",
)

if isinstance(df.columns, pd.MultiIndex) and df.columns.nlevels > 1:
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)

data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=df)
cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.run()

plotter = plot.Plot()

fig = plotter.plot(cerebro.runstrats[0][0],)[0]

axes = fig.get_axes()
ax = axes[2] # main graph

rect = plt.Rectangle((0.1, 0.1), 0.8, 0.8, transform=ax.transAxes, linewidth=2, edgecolor="green", facecolor="none")
ax.add_patch(rect)

fig.savefig("backtrader_plot.png")

plt.show()


